# updating User using webvimark in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, webvimark

I am using webvimark module in Yii2. I have created a My Account page, where a user can update his/her information. I am unable to update user updated info, although I am able to fetch user info and display in a form on my-account page.

Below is my updated webvimark User class:

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $country
 * @property string $card_number
 * @property string $payment_type
 * @property string $expiring_month
 * @property string $expiring_year
 * @property string $expiry_date
 * @property string $csc
 * @property string $card_address
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $state
 * @property string $zip_code
 * @property string $user_type
 * @property string $fax
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $user_type
 * @property string $company_name
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $email_confirmed
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $confirmation_token
 * @property string $bind_to_ip
 * @property string $registration_ip
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $superadmin
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 */
class User extends UserIdentity
{
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_BANNED = -1;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $gridRoleSearch;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $repeat_password;

    /**
     * Store result in singleton to prevent multiple db requests with multiple calls
     *
     * @param bool $fromSingleton
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getCurrentUser($fromSingleton = true)
    {
        if ( !$fromSingleton )
        {
            return static::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        }

        $user = Singleton::getData('__currentUser');

        if ( !$user )
        {
            $user = static::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);

            Singleton::setData('__currentUser', $user);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Assign role to user
     *
     * @param int  $userId
     * @param string $roleName
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function assignRole($userId, $roleName)
    {
        try
        {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                ->insert(Yii::$app->getModule('user-management')->auth_assignment_table, [
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'item_name' => $roleName,
                    'created_at' => time(),
                ])->execute();

            AuthHelper::invalidatePermissions();

            return true;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Revoke role from user
     *
     * @param int    $userId
     * @param string $roleName
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function revokeRole($userId, $roleName)
    {
        $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->delete(Yii::$app->getModule('user-management')->auth_assignment_table, ['user_id' => $userId, 'item_name' => $roleName])
            ->execute() > 0;

        if ( $result )
        {
            AuthHelper::invalidatePermissions();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|array $roles
     * @param bool         $superAdminAllowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function hasRole($roles, $superAdminAllowed = true)
    {
        if ( $superAdminAllowed AND Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin )
        {
            return true;
        }
        $roles = (array)$roles;

        AuthHelper::ensurePermissionsUpToDate();

        return array_intersect($roles, Yii::$app->session->get(AuthHelper::SESSION_PREFIX_ROLES,[])) !== [];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $permission
     * @param bool   $superAdminAllowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function hasPermission($permission, $superAdminAllowed = true)
    {
        if ( $superAdminAllowed AND Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin )
        {
            return true;
        }

        AuthHelper::ensurePermissionsUpToDate();

        return in_array($permission, Yii::$app->session->get(AuthHelper::SESSION_PREFIX_PERMISSIONS,[]));
    }

    /**
     * Useful for Menu widget
     *
     * <example>
     *  ...
     *      [ 'label'=>'Some label', 'url'=>['/site/index'], 'visible'=>User::canRoute(['/site/index']) ]
     *  ...
     * </example>
     *
     * @param string|array $route
     * @param bool         $superAdminAllowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function canRoute($route, $superAdminAllowed = true)
    {
        if ( $superAdminAllowed AND Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin )
        {
            return true;
        }

        $baseRoute = AuthHelper::unifyRoute($route);

        if ( Route::isFreeAccess($baseRoute) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        AuthHelper::ensurePermissionsUpToDate();

        return Route::isRouteAllowed($baseRoute, Yii::$app->session->get(AuthHelper::SESSION_PREFIX_ROUTES,[]));
    }

    /**
     * getStatusList
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getStatusList()
    {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_ACTIVE   => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Active'),
            self::STATUS_INACTIVE => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Inactive'),
            self::STATUS_BANNED   => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Banned'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * getStatusValue
     *
     * @param string $val
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getStatusValue($val)
    {
        $ar = self::getStatusList();

        return isset( $ar[$val] ) ? $ar[$val] : $val;
    }

    /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return Yii::$app->getModule('user-management')->user_table;
    }

    /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'required'],
            [['name','phone','user_type'], 'required'],


            ['username', 'unique'],
            ['username', 'trim'],
            [['company_name', 'name', 'phone','fax','address','payment_type','card_number','expiry_date','csc','card_address','country','city','state','zip_code'], 'trim'],    

            [['status', 'email_confirmed'], 'integer'],

            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'validateEmailConfirmedUnique'],

            ['bind_to_ip', 'validateBindToIp'],
            ['bind_to_ip', 'trim'],
            ['bind_to_ip', 'string', 'max' => 255],

            ['password', 'required', 'on'=>['newUser', 'changePassword']],
            ['password', 'string', 'max' => 255, 'on'=>['newUser', 'changePassword']],
            ['password', 'trim', 'on'=>['newUser', 'changePassword']],

            ['repeat_password', 'required', 'on'=>['newUser', 'changePassword']],
            ['repeat_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Check that there is no such confirmed E-mail in the system
     */
    public function validateEmailConfirmedUnique()
    {
        if ( $this->email )
        {
            $exists = User::findOne([
                'email'           => $this->email,
                'email_confirmed' => 1,
            ]);

            if ( $exists AND $exists->id != $this->id )
            {
                $this->addError('email', UserManagementModule::t('front', 'This E-mail already exists'));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate bind_to_ip attr to be in correct format
     */
    public function validateBindToIp()
    {
        if ( $this->bind_to_ip )
        {
            $ips = explode(',', $this->bind_to_ip);

            foreach ($ips as $ip)
            {
                if ( !filter_var(trim($ip), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) )
                {
                    $this->addError('bind_to_ip', UserManagementModule::t('back', "Wrong format. Enter valid IPs separated by comma"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id'                 => 'ID',
            'username'           => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Login'),
            'superadmin'         => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Superadmin'),
            'confirmation_token' => 'Confirmation Token',
            'registration_ip'    => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Registration IP'),
            'bind_to_ip'         => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Bind to IP'),
            'status'             => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Status'),
            'gridRoleSearch'     => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Roles'),
            'created_at'         => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Created'),
            'updated_at'         => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Updated'),
            'password'           => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Password'),
            'repeat_password'    => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'Repeat password'),
            'email_confirmed'    => UserManagementModule::t('back', 'E-mail confirmed'),
            'email'              => 'E-mail',
            //'user_type'              => 'E-mail',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::className(), ['name' => 'item_name'])
            ->viaTable(Yii::$app->getModule('user-management')->auth_assignment_table, ['user_id'=>'id']);
    }


    /**
     * Make sure user will not deactivate himself and superadmin could not demote himself
     * Also don't let non-superadmin edit superadmin
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if ( $insert )
        {
            if ( php_sapi_name() != 'cli' )
            {
                $this->registration_ip = LittleBigHelper::getRealIp();
            }
            $this->generateAuthKey();
        }
        else
        {
            // Console doesn't have Yii::$app->user, so we skip it for console
            if ( php_sapi_name() != 'cli' )
            {
                if ( Yii::$app->user->id == $this->id )
                {
                    // Make sure user will not deactivate himself
                    $this->status = static::STATUS_ACTIVE;

                    // Superadmin could not demote himself
                    if ( Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin AND $this->superadmin != 1 )
                    {
                        $this->superadmin = 1;
                    }
                }

                // Don't let non-superadmin edit superadmin
                if ( isset($this->oldAttributes['superadmin']) && !Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin && $this->oldAttributes['superadmin'] == 1 )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // If password has been set, than create password hash
        if ( $this->password )
        {
            $this->setPassword($this->password);
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }

    /**
     * Don't let delete yourself and don't let non-superadmin delete superadmin
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function beforeDelete()
    {
        // Console doesn't have Yii::$app->user, so we skip it for console
        if ( php_sapi_name() != 'cli' )
        {
            // Don't let delete yourself
            if ( Yii::$app->user->id == $this->id )
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Don't let non-superadmin delete superadmin
            if ( !Yii::$app->user->isSuperadmin AND $this->superadmin == 1 )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return parent::beforeDelete();
    }
}
```

and the AuthController class because I have created my view file (my-account.php inside auth folder of webvimark). My AuthController action function is as under:

```
public function actionMyAccount()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ( Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
        {
            return $this->goHome();
        }



        //if ( Yii::$app->request->post() AND $model->validate())
        if ( Yii::$app->request->post())
        {
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
             {
                $model->save();
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', "Account has been updated!");
             }           
        }
        else
        {
            $model = User::getCurrentUser();    

        }

        return $this->render('my-account', ['model' => $model,]);
    }
```

Comment: show the related code

Comment: Please add the ceode updating your question and format the code properly  ..

Comment: I updated rules() in User class by added the missing variables, now I am able to update a few values, not all.

Comment: what are the fields that you can not do the update?

Comment: I am unable to udpate fields like country, city, state, zip_code etc.

Comment: just checked, nothing is updated at database tables. Only updated textfields are shown on view but not in database.

Comment: I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you must declare the field you don't validate by the safe attribute

```
[['company_name', 'name', 'phone','fax','address','payment_type',    
     'card_number','expiry_date','csc','card_address','country',
     'city','state','zip_code'], 'safe'],
```

or could be is a validation problem

try using (just for debug)  save(false)

```
    //if ( Yii::$app->request->post() AND $model->validate())
    if ( Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
         {
            $model->save(false);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', "Account has been updated!");
         }  else {
            var_dump('model not loaded');
         }

    }
```

if in this way the values are saved in db the is a validation rule problem .

You can get the validation error this way

```
if ($model->validate()) {
   // all inputs are valid
} else {
    // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
   $errors = $model->errors;
   var_dump($errors);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the $model->save() is performed i have update the answer with a debugger var_dump if the model is not loaded ..

Comment: try with the test for model load

Comment: Yes, it was a validation error. Now, I get validation error like "abc@yahoo.com" has been taken. This is the username. I am trying to update, not insert a new record. I want to update any column but not username in a row.

Comment: Explain better .. the original question is for updating user  .. this is solved?

Comment: The exact validation error: array(1) { ["username"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(48) "Login "saller@yahoo.com" has already been taken." } }

Comment: OK.. the problem is that you are using   $model = new User(); this mean you are creating a new user and not updating an existinting user.  for update you should use the model related to the user you want change ..

Comment: No you don't need comment the $model = new User() but assign to $model = the model of the user you want update .. your User module should give you a way for retrive the model of a user .. the assign to $model .. and all will work ..

Comment: Thanks a lot @scaisEdge for the help. i am now good, all is working. I am able to update user. Actually I didn't want to create profile separately. I wanted to use the User editing functionality in webvimark (which is an amazing module).

Comment: I upvoted so your answer is accepted or I have to do something else to mark it as accepted ?

Comment: You can also mark the answer as accepted...  there is a check mark below the up and down arrow for upvote and downvote .. be sure don't press the downvote arrow ..

Comment: done accepting the answer. Thanks again @scaisEdge. You are a hero.